# How can I make list comprehension have "or?"

Tags: python, list

I am trying to get the list of links from a Google search:

```
def google_word(word):
    headers={'User-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.17763'}
    url = 'https://google.com/search?q={}'.format(word)
    res= requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    tree= html.fromstring(res.text)
    li = tree.xpath("//a[@href]") #list of links that conatin href
    y = [link.get('href') for link in li if link.get('href').startswith("https://") if "google" not in link.get('href')]
```

Now, this code collects the right link that starts with "`https://"`, what I want to do is add the `"http://"` as well. What do I need to add to the list comprehension in order to make that work (I am trying to do it in one line)?

Comment: Try `[link.get('href') for link in li if (link.get('href').startswith("https://") or "google" not in link.get('href') )]`

Comment: `link.get("href").startswith("http://") or link.get("href").startswith("https://")`? `link.get("href").startswith(("http://", "https://"))`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add tuple to the startswith

```
y = [link.get('href') for link in li if link.get('href').startswith(("https://", "http://")) if "google" not in link.get('href')]
```

Comment: ok so now it comapres "http://" or "https://" then checks "google" not in href right?

Comment: yep, that's what it does

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
y = [link.get('href') for link in li if link.get('href').startswith("https://") if "google" not in link.get('href')]
```

Should be the below instead:

```
y = [link.get('href') for link in li if link.get('href').startswith(("https://", "http://"))]
```

Comment: 'y = [link.get('href') for link in li if link.get('href').startswith("https://") or "google" not in link.get('href')]' this gets links that i don't want,however,your first solution works

Comment: Done, it's great now

Comment: @hadesfv Thanks\

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to do this. Here's how:

```
y = [link.get('href') for link in li if re.match("https*://", link.get('href')) if "google" not in link.get('href')]
```

This will match from zero to unlimited number of occurrences of `s` (there will be 0 or 1 in real situations).

Comment: if I may ask if i am doing this for 1 million lists, is using regex faster than `startswith` to find the links?

Comment: ? will macht only zero to one so use it instead of *

Comment: @Lee it works he meant `https*://` the s is either 0 or 1 (http or https) hence it will return sucessful for both cases

Comment: @hadesfv To be honest, I do not have any clue about performance of those two approaches.

Comment: @hadesfv It works with * but with ? it will not work for the httpsssssssssssssssss:// case

Comment: @Lee It will be True in case of httpssss and https

Comment: @hadesfv that is why use ? instead of * so that it will not be true in case of httpssss

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to get search results from google, I would suggest you to use the `googlesearch` library itself.

It would be much easier for you to get the results. There is no need of scraping the entire query page and search for getting results. It provides you with both `http` and `https` links. Here's an article that might be helpul to you.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/performing-google-search-using-python-code/

Comment: Thanks for the new idea sir, this uses `BeautifulSoup` does it make slower than my method ?

Comment: this module takes twice as long to run

Comment: I didn't check the performance of it. But looks like there are more options when using the api instead of direct scraping the search results page.

Comment: what do you mean API, is there an API for a search query?

Comment: I mean to say library. 
These might be helpful to you.
https://github.com/anthonyhseb/googlesearch
https://pypi.org/project/google-search/